# popup is displayed as "Unable to launch" while running the code in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried the below code and while running the code I'm getting the popup as "The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches"

Can u please help me with this....

Thanks

**Full Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Gmail_Login {

/**

    @param args

*/

public static void main(String[] args) {

// objects and variables instantiation

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier";

// launch the firefox browser and open the application url

driver.get(appUrl);

// maximize the browser window

driver.manage().window().maximize();

// declare and initialize the variable to store the expected title of the webpage.

String expectedTitle = " Sign in - Google Accounts ";

// fetch the title of the web page and save it into a string variable

String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

// compare the expected title of the page with the actual title of the page and print the result

if (expectedTitle.equals(actualTitle))

{

System.out.println("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");

}

else

{

System.out.println("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");

}

// enter a valid username in the email textbox

WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));

username.clear();

username.sendKeys("TestSelenium");

// enter a valid password in the password textbox

WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));

password.clear();

password.sendKeys("password123");

// click on the Sign in button

WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));

SignInButton.click();

// close the web browser

driver.close();

System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");

// terminate the program

System.exit(0);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I executed the code you shared. It did not throw the error you mentioned. The only change I made to your code was setting **System** property **webdriver.gecko.driver**, as I am using the latest Selenium library and it require setting this path for using Firefox. I would recommend you as well to use the latest Selenium [library](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). You can download the **geckodriver** from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest).

Before initializing the **FirefoxDriver** object, you need to set the relevant System property. You can do that in following way:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<path_to_geckodriver.exe>");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.